# Recharts join disconnected lines

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

When there is null in the time-series data, Recharts is not joining the dots and considering it as an independent point in the Line chart.

I want to join the disconnected points. How can I achieve that?

```
const data = [
  {
    ts: 1641275508,
    uv: 4000,
    pv: null,
    amt: 2400
  },
  {
    ts: 1641275608,
    uv: null,
    pv: 1398,
    amt: 2210
  },
  {
    ts: 1641275708,
    uv: 2000,
    pv: 9800,
    amt: 2290
  },
  {
    ts: 1641275808,
    uv: null,
    pv: 3908,
    amt: 2000
  },
  {
    ts: 1641275908,
    uv: 1890,
    pv: null,
    amt: 2181
  },
  {
    ts: 1641276008,
    uv: 2390,
    pv: 3800,
    amt: 2500
  },
  {
    ts: 1641276108,
    uv: null,
    pv: 4300,
    amt: 2100
  }
];
```

Current Result
[image: Current Result]

Expected Result
[image: Expected Result]

https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-line-chart-forked-mozqo?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be achieved using `connectNulls` props by components like Line, Area etc.

```js
    <LineChart
      width={500}
      height={300}
      data={data}
      margin={{
        top: 5,
        right: 30,
        left: 20,
        bottom: 5
      }}
    >
      <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
      <XAxis dataKey="ts" type={"number"} domain={["dataMin", "dataMax"]} />
      <YAxis />
      <Tooltip />
      <Legend />
      <Line type="monotone" connectNulls dataKey="pv" stroke="#8884d8" />
      <Line type="monotone" connectNulls dataKey="uv" stroke="#82ca9d" />
    </LineChart>
```

Solution:

https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-line-chart-forked-mdkeb?file=/src/App.tsx

[image: Chart Render]